# Необходимо "раскрасить" код сниппета после его динамического изменения

Tags: javascript

В элемент динамически шаблонизатором вставляется код сниппета, но раскраска при отображении кода не срабатывает. Как обновить содержимое тегов  для срабатывания раскраски сниппета?

- ДО ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- ПОСЛЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// вставляем код в сниппет
$('#code_monitor').html('/* тут код для вставки */');

// тут как то нужно обновить сниппет, для того чтобы "раскрасить код"
```

```html
<!-- код HTML отображения сниппета -->
<div>
  <pre class="line-numbers code_monitor">
    <code id="code_monitor" class="language-javascript"></code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте `append()/ prepend()/ appendTo()` так как они работают с узлами DOM. `html()` возьмите за привычку использовать только для текста

Comment: @ddeadlink, что? `.html()` для текста? А `.text()` для чего тогда, по-вашему?

Comment: просто .html() перезатирал старый код... но написал так и ничего не изменилось в лучшую сторону: $('#code_monitor').empty().append('/* тут код для вставки */');